# Can a TensorFlow model run as a Linux/Unix service?

Tags: linux, unix, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have built a TensorFlow model using TensorFlow’s high-level machine learning API (tf.contrib.learn). I need to run this model as a Linux/Unix service. Or export the model as an executable. Is this possible? And if yes how can I do so?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to run a [tensorflow server](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/) on your local machine, then connect to it via RPC. You can put the serving command in `/etc/initd` or `/etc/systemd`.

Comment: I need to make predictions on my trained model from my server since I need the prediction response within 300 milliseconds (ideally 100 milliseconds) which is not feasible if we make a call to the model which is on another server (TensorFlow Server). Any idea as to how can it be achieved?

Comment: You can still do RPC on your local machine. That should not cost above 10ms. Otherwise, you can use the [C API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api.h).

Comment: How can I make a RPC call from my local machine which takes less than 10 seconds? Currently, I have a Ubuntu system wherein I have set up TensorFlow Serving and exported the trained model. However, when I am making the predictions on the saved model it takes approximately 2-3minutes to make the predictions and print it in my console

Comment: I was talking about the RPC overhead itself. If the model takes so much time (presuming it's computational cost, not data transfer), then you have to either create a smaller model, batch up predictions, or parallelize. Probably a combination of all three in your case.

Comment: Even if I run the sample programs provided by TensorFlow Serving, for instance, the "mnist_client" program, it takes around 3-4 seconds for the response (predictions) to be printed. That makes me wonder if my model is large or does it generally take that long for any model?

Comment: Oh, there's a fixed cost of loading up the tensorflow python packages that is around 4 seconds (it takes about 8000 stat(2) calls). So you should only load that up once, or use c++ which typically adds less than 10ms startup time.

Comment: Cold you please explain the meaning of "only load that up once"?

Comment: You have to stay inside the program. Take a look at `do_inference`. You have to stay in that loop and receive the results asynchronously. You'd get the inputs from, say, stdin.

Comment: Is there a way in which I can keep the trained model running in the background so that the model doesn't have to be loaded every time a prediction is to be made. Will this make it faster?

Comment: That's what tensorflow serving does. Unfortunately, the python client has a huge startup time. It's not loading models or anything, just the python tensorflow library itself. So either you use the C/C++ api, or you modify the python one to just startup once and get inputs incrementally.